# Calculating centripetal force in a double pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, centripetal-force

From my understanding, in a double pendulum system, the Lagrangian gives the path of least action. But is it possible to find the centripetal force exerted by a pendulum at a point in time?
From Euler-Lagrange's equation, can we obtain the angular velocity of both pendulums and use them to find the centripetal force, as per the Newtonian formula $F = m\omega^2 r$ where the equation for $\omega$ of both pendulums is obtained?

Answer (score 2):

Newton's second law in polar coordinates is

$$m\mathbf a=m(\ddot r-r\dot\theta^2)\,\hat r+m(r\ddot\theta+2\dot r\dot\theta)\,\hat \theta$$

Of course, this is only mostly useful for the first mass of the double pendulum, as for this mass $\dot r=\ddot r=0$ about where the mass hangs from.

The second mass does not move about a fixed point, but I suppose you could do some math to express its motion in terms of polar coordinates about where the first mass hangs from. Note that $\ddot r\neq0$ here, so the centripetal force component is not just given by $mr\omega^2$.

So the answer is yes. If you have determined $\theta(t)$ for each mass then you should be able to determine the force components using polar coordinates/vectors. Note that in general the acceleration for both masses will not be purely centripetal.